# How to monitor pool stats in Atomikos with prometheus

Tags: prometheus, atomikos

We were using hikari with prometheus to monitor pool stat. Now we need to switch to Atomikos because of XaDatasource and global transaction. Is there already some way how we keep similar monitoring pool stat in Atomikos or we need to implement it from zero ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way without writing your own, however, it's in the commercial version of Atomikos (module is named `transactions-jmx`), it provides monitoring for:

- UniqueResourceName
- MinPoolSize
- MaxPoolSize
- AvailableConnectionsInPool
- CurrentPoolSize
- BusyConnectionsInPool
- PercentageOfPoolCapacityUsed
- LastPoolExhaustionHappenedAt
- LastReapHappenedAt

In which you can inject your own beans to monitor:

```java
@Bean
public JmxAtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean jmxAtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean(DataSource xaDataSource) {
    JmxAtomikosDataSourceBean bean = new JmxAtomikosDataSourceBean();
    bean.setMonitoredBean((AtomikosDataSourceBean) xaDataSource);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public JmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBeanMBean jmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBeanMBean() {
    JmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBean bean = new JmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
    bean.setMonitoredBean((AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean) jmsConnectionFactory());
    return bean;
}
```

Afterwards, you can export them however you like, for  example, using [prometheus/jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).

Hope it helps.